# Call class methods from View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am quiet new to Django and I come from ASP.Net background.

I am trying to achieve OOP concept in one of the web application.

I have a model which maintains a movie list

**url.py**

```
from movies import views

url(r'^recent/$', views.recentlyadded)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class MovieManager(models.Model):
    def title_count(self, keyword):
        return self.filter(title__icontains=keyword).count()

class Movie(models.Model):
    movieid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    objects = MovieManager()
```

I am trying to return the movie titles based on the keyword using custom manager MovieManager

**views.py**

```
from movies.models import Movie

def recentlyadded(request):
    r = Movie.objects.title_count('night')
    return HttpResponse("test")
```

This throws error AttributeError: **'Manager' object has no attribute 'title_count'**

How to call models.py method in recentlyadded view.py function?

I want to use recentlyadded() method in multiple views/ functions in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view code is correct, but not the model - `MovieManager` should inherit from `models.Manager`, not from `models.Model`. Not finding an explicitely declared `Manager`, the metaclass overwrite `Movie.objects` with a default manager.

FWIW you could have found out by yourself by inspecting `Movie.objects` in a Python shell (or by reading the source code for `django.db.models.base.ModelBase`).

Comment: I agree with you that I could have read more carefully, I certainly be cautious from next time.

Answer (score 1):

To return the movie title. You probably would have this one the model.py file

Do it at the end if the model file

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```